# Animations not working on custom actor in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, sprites, texture-atlas, tweening

I have this code for rendering a sprite, retrieved from a TextureAtlas

```
public class SpriteActor extends Actor {
private Sprite sprite;

public SpriteActor(TextureAtlas atlas, String spriteName) {
    sprite = atlas.createSprite(spriteName);
    this.setWidth(sprite.getWidth());
    this.setHeight(sprite.getHeight());
    this.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    sprite.setPosition(this.getX(), this.getY());
    sprite.setOrigin(this.getOriginX(), this.getOriginY());
    sprite.setRotation(this.getRotation());
    sprite.setScale(this.getScaleX(), this.getScaleY());
}

@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    Color color = new Color(this.getColor().r, this.getColor().g,
            this.getColor().b, this.getColor().a * parentAlpha);

    batch.setColor(color);
    sprite.setColor(color);

    sprite.draw(batch);

}

}
```

EDIT: Using actions with a Image actor in the same stage works, It's only my actor that doesn't

When I set the transparency like this : `actor.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5f);`
I can see the sprite becoming half transparent; or, if I set the position manually (`actor.setPosition(0, 30);`) I see the sprite to the correct position; but if I try to use actions (`import static com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions.*;` [...] `actor.addAction(fadeIn(3)` or `actor.addAction(forever(rotateBy(45), delay(1))`) they just do nothing.

Do I need to implement something to have predefined actions working on my code? Or what do I need to make this code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just speculation:

Maybe you forgot to call `act()` on your Stage that has all the Actors.
Actions are updated per frame through the `act()` method on each Actor which is called by Stage's `act()`.

```
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); 
    stage.draw();
}
```

From https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d

**Edit**: Real problem was overriding act() without calling super.act() which updates list of Action as found in Actor class source.

Comment: Sorry, I call act right before draw. I should have added my update code...

Comment: Ok, you may want to look at the source of Actor class since you're overriding act() which probably does more complex stuff than what you got there. Try calling super.act() first.